# How to process userAccountControl array to know if a user is enabled?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have to query a domain controller for the enabled state of a specific account. I have to do this with LDAP because the machine making the query is not joined to the domain.

My code is as follows:

```cs
public async Task<bool> IsUserEnabled(string samAccountName)
{
    var server = "[OMITTED]";
    var username = "[OMITTED]";
    var password = "[OMITTED]";
    var domain = "[OMITTED]";
    var query = $"(&(objectCategory=person)(SAMAccountName={samAccountName}))";
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
    var conn = new LdapConnection(server);
    try
    {
        conn.Credential = credentials;
        conn.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        conn.Bind();
        var domain_parts = domain.Split('.');
        if (domain_parts.Length < 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid domain name (name used: \"{domain}\").");
        }
        var target = $"dc={domain_parts[0]},dc={domain_parts[1]}";
        var search_scope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        var search_request = new SearchRequest(target, query, search_scope, null);
        var temp_response = await Task<DirectoryResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
            conn.BeginSendRequest,
            (iar) => conn.EndSendRequest(iar),
            search_request,
            PartialResultProcessing.NoPartialResultSupport,
            null);
        var response = temp_response as SearchResponse;
        if (response == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("LDAP server answered NULL.");
        }
        var entries = response.Entries;
        var entry = entries[0].Attributes["userAccountControl"];
        var values = entry.GetValues(typeof(byte[])).First();
        var output = (byte[])values;
        var result = false;
        return result;
    }
    catch (LdapException lex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error querying LDAP server", lex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unknown error", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In the lines

```cs
var values = entry.GetValues(typeof(byte[])).First(); 
var output = (byte[])values;
```

I get a byte array with what I think is the current user's flags, but I don't know how to process this data in order to know if the user is enabled or not.

Most advice I found is that I should convert this to an integer and OR-it with 2 in order to know, but `Convert.ToInt32(output)` throws an exception (`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.`) and using `BitConverter.ToInt32(output, 0)` also throws an exception (`Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.`)

One thing I noticed is that the array is 3 bytes long, and I don't know if that's right.

Ive queried 2 users: one (we know this one is enabled in the AD) returns a `[53, 49, 50]` array, and the other one (this one is disabled) returns `[53, 52, 54]`.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the `userAccountControl` attribute is a 4-byte integer value (a bit mask), so why would you try and convert this into a byte array at all?

```
var entry = entries[0].Attributes["userAccountControl"];
// return True if the UF_ACCOUNT_DISABLE flag (bit no. 1) is not set
// meaning the user is Enabled
return (entry & 2) == 0;
```

<sup>See [userAccountControl](http://www.selfadsi.org/ads-attributes/user-userAccountControl.htm)</sup>